# How to count the objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, jasmine

I have a function which takes an array of many data types.

```js
function count(totalObjs) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {

        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

To only count the *objects* in an array, you **can't** do this:

```
typeof x == "object"
```

Because this returns `true` for an object, an array, or `null`.

It's best to check the `toString` - it'll return `[object Object]` for objects.

```js
const arr = [1,{},[],null,null,'foo',3,4,5,{},{},{},'foo'];

const count = arrObj => arrObj.filter(e => e && e.toString() == "[object Object]").length;

console.log(count(arr));
```

Comment: Thanks mate. but its not running against my test code.Can u please explain bit more?

Comment: What do you mean @Chandler? Click `Run code snippet` above, it works perfectly.

Comment: yeah it working perfectly in code snippet but its not passing my test.Its showing empty..

Comment: You don't need a `toString` check. Just `=> e && typeof e === "object"`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That would keep the arrays as well - OP only wants to keep objects.

Comment: @JackBashford - Arrays *are* objects. Does the OP really want to keep objects created by (for instance) `new Foo` (assuming Foo is an ES5-style constructor function) but not arrays, dates, etc.? I don't see that in the question.

Comment: Look at the demo code - in the last check (the really long vertical one), there are 4 objects and 1 array, and the OP expects the output to be 4.

Comment: Very strange requirement which should have been called out explicitly (but then, that's not the only issue with this question...). :-) If I were answering it, I'd point out how arbitrary it is and that it will miss out other kinds of objects (dates, regular expressions...).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to count up the number of occurrences *without* creating a nearly-unused intermediate array, you can use `reduce`:

```js
const count = arr => arr.reduce((a, item) => a + (item && item.constructor === Object), 0);

console.log(count([1, [], null, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much typical , You just need to extract the object having keys in it and you can get count of them

```
Taking an array having null, array, blank object and string and object having value in it.

    var arr = [1, [], null, 3, 4, 5, {key: 'val'}, {}, {}, 'foo']

    const result = arr.filter(val => (val instanceof Object && Object.keys(val).length > 0));

    Now get the count of objects having values in it.

    console.log('result', result.length);
```